Safe utilization of fork() to create multiple children, without data races
I'm writing a small program which uses fork() to create 4 child threads.  I am new to working with fork() and want to make certain I am using the most thread-safe approach.  The issue I am having does not seem to have negative effects on the outcome but it does seem to indicate that there is some indeterminate behavior which I would like to address.  Consider the code below:
pid_t pid = -2;
std::vector<pid_t> pids;
uint16_t nextPort = startingPort;
std::cout << "Creating " << noThreads << " threads\n";
for(int i = 0; i < noThreads; ++i)
{
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    if(pid)
    {
        pid = fork();
        pids.push_back(pid);
        std::cout << "Created PID: " << (intmax_t)pid << "\t" << pids.size() << " total\n";
    }
}

Program output:
Creating 4 threads
0
Created PID: 521042     1 total
1
Created PID: 521043     2 total
2
Created PID: 0  1 total
1
2
3
Created PID: 521044     3 total
3
Created PID: 0  2 total
2
3
Created PID: 0  3 total
Created PID: 521045     4 total
3
Cleaning up

The output varies but what appears to be consistently happening is that when a child is created by fork, there is a moment in time between when the new thread exists and the return value of fork() in the child process is set to zero, causing the logging to be indeterminate.  At least that is what seems like is happening.  However, strangely enough it doesn't seem to be filling the vector with 0's as I would expect.
Is there a more thread-safe way of implementing this, still us?
Full code below.  please don't beat me up on the clean-up.  Still working on this.
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// An arbitrary port value for the first thread
// subsequent threads will each increment by 1
constexpr uint16_t startingPort = 7777;

// Number of children to fork
constexpr short noThreads = 4;

// UDP message buffer max size
constexpr uint8_t bufferSize = 60;

typedef std::atomic_int atomic_pid_t;
atomic_pid_t pid;

// Send a message to the local host on the post specified
void sendUdpMessage(std::string buffer, unsigned short port)
{
    int sock =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sendto(sock, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size(), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    close(sock);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Fork n number of threads and store the child
    // PID's in a vector
    pid = -2;
    std::vector<pid_t> pids;
    uint16_t nextPort = startingPort;
    std::cout << "Creating " << noThreads << " threads\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < noThreads; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        if(pid)
        {
            pid = fork();
            pids.push_back(pid);
            std::cout << "Created PID: " << (intmax_t)pid << "\t" << pids.size() << " total\n";
        }
    }

    // While the vector of PID's is not empty, determine if
    // the current process PID is in the vector
    // if so, send a message.  increment the port value
    // erase the pid entry
    std::vector<pid_t>::iterator currentPos;
    while(pids.size() > 0)
    {
        currentPos = std::find(pids.begin(), pids.end(), pid);
        if(currentPos != pids.end())
        {
            char buffer[bufferSize];
            snprintf(buffer, bufferSize, "Writing buffer to port %hu from pid %hu\n", nextPort, (intmax_t)pid);
            sendUdpMessage(buffer, nextPort);
            ++nextPort;
            pids.erase(currentPos);
        }
    }

    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0:
            puts("Cleaning up\n");
            for(auto it : pids)
            {
                kill(it, SIGINT);
            }
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

*** update ***
I still do not have a resolution but I tried something which I thought might work.  It does not and I am if the problem is different then I suspected.
First off I did update the print statements to use std::endl which unfortunately did not help
The next thing i tried on the assumption that the child function begins executing before setting the return value. so I updated the if statement to
if(getppid() != pid && pid)
{
    pid = getpid()
    pid = fork()
    ...
}

However this also did not make a difference.

Please note one important thing - fork() creates a new process, not a new thread.

You are correct.  bad terminology on my part.

Unless you use synchronization methods like semaphores, it's unpredictable which process will continue first after you fork a child.

This has nothing to do with thread-safety, which is related to using shared data in different threads of the same process. With multiple processes, nothing is shared unless you explicitly use shared memory.

@Barmar, perhaps I am using the wrong terminology but the virtual address space is shared between two processes, which is the issue I am trying to address.

No it isn't. Each process has an independent copy of the address space.

Make sure you flush output with endl. Otherwise, the child process gets a copy of the output buffer that hasn't been flushed in the parent.

@Barmar -- hey, a real use for std::endl!

@mreff555 What are you expecting to happen? You know that fork() returns the child PID in the original process and 0 in the new child process? You should get a vector of 0's only in the child-child-child process (and PID-PID-PID in the original process, 0-PID-PID in the first fork, PID-0-PID in it's sibling, 0-0-PID in it's child, etc.)

@Sir Nate, I do.  By this logic, the if() statement above should not affect children.  However, from the logs I can see that children appear to be entering the loop causing an extra line to be printed to the screen.  I am trying to prevent this as it may result in the child creating additional forks.

@mreff555 I had overlooked the if(). Given that, your output actually makes complete sense - you have one process printing i=0, it and the first child printing i=1, three printing i=2, and all four printing i=3. Additionally, you have the parent process printing the creation of each child, and you have each child printing a single time the line Created PID: 0  _ total. Each child is created inside the loop, and continues through it (you don't have a break).

Ahhh.  I see.  Adding the else { break; } cleared things up
